# Unable create a table - ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I'm trying to execute this simple command:

```
create table foo
(clo int primary key unsigned auto_increment);
```

But I get this error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'unsigned auto_increment)' at
>   line 2

Comment: For reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html. In particular, look at the column_definition and data_type non-terminals in the grammar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried putting `int` and `unsigned` together and it worked fine:

```
create table foo
(clo int unsigned primary key auto_increment );
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is a little off. Try this:

```
create table `foo` (
  `clo` int unsigned auto_increment ,
  PRIMARY KEY(`clo`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```