# create table: Error 1064 (42000): my sql syntax

Tags: mysql

I am getting an get an error in a create table statement in MySQL server 5.2.  The error message is

> 1064 (42000): my sql syntax

My query is:

```
create table places(
  place_id int(10) not null auto_increment,
  p_name varchar(15) not null,
  lat float(15,11) not null,
  primary key(place_id)
);
```

Comment: What error exactly? What did you tried to fix it?

Comment: Works for me also http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/1fec6

Comment: create table places(
  place_id int(10) not null auto_increment primary key,
  p_name varchar(15) not null,
  lat float(15,11) not null
);  and check that your database is selected

Comment: Where's the rest of the error message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable create a table - ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2758649/unable-create-a-table-error-1064-42000-you-have-an-error-in-your-sql-syntax) and about three dozen others here. Please try at least a basic search on the error message before posting a new question here.

Comment: thanks, i could solve this error